# Как скрыть в медиа запросе только те елементы которые мне не нужны

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет!Вот так выглядит шапка моего сайта
[image: Шапка]
Мне нужно скрыть

```
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Delivery & Payment</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Guarantee</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
```

Вот мой HTML

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import FaAlignJustify from 'react-icons/lib/fa/align-justify';
import FaShoppingCart from 'react-icons/lib/fa/shopping-cart';
class Header extends Component {
     render() {
         return(
         <div>
             <div className="HeaderMain">
             <div className="DropMenu" >
             <ul className ="MenuButtons" id="TopNav" >
                     <li className="MenuHeader"><FaAlignJustify /></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><img src="/images/portland.jpg" alt="portlandlogo"/></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Delivery & Payment</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Guarantee</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><div className="CartMain">
                < FaShoppingCart /><span>Cart</span>
                <div className="Cart-container"><span className="Cart-span"></span><span className="Cart-text">0</span></div></div></li>
                <li className="Visible"><button className="HeaderBtn">Sign in</button></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <hr/>

            </div>
         </div>);


    }
}

export default Header;
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Montserrat-regular';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.svg#Montserrat Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    unicode-range: U+0020-2044;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:'Montserrat-SemiBold';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.svg#Montserrat SemiBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    unicode-range: U+0020-2044;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

li{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

hr{
  border: none;
  background-color: #B9BED1 !important;
  color: #B9BED1 !important;
  height: 1px;
}

.MenuButtons{
  margin-top: 37px;
}

.MenuButtons > li{
  display: inline-block;

   }

  .MenuButtons > li >a{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 29px;
  color: #343e5c;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;

  }

  .MenuButtons > li >div>span{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right:7px; 
  }

  .MenuButtons > li >img{
    margin-right:157px;
   }

   .MenuButtons > li:first-child{
     display: none;
   }

.Cart-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }

.Cart-span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); }

.Cart-text {
  position: relative;

  padding: 0em 0.65em;
 }

.CartMain {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:29px; 
}

.HeaderMain {
  display: inline;
  color: #343e5c;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif; }

.HeaderBtn {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  width: 85px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #e3e8f0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
    color: #343e5c }

.DropMenu {
      margin-left: 115px;
      font-size: 20px;
  }

.MenuHeader{
    margin-right:75px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width:1159px){
  .MenuButtons > li >img{
    margin-right:75px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1073px){
  .DropMenu {
    margin-left: 35px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
  /* .MenuButtons > li:not(:first-child & .MenuButtons > li >img & .CartMain & .HeaderBtn ){
    display:none;

     } */
     .MenuButtons > li :not(.Visible){
       display: none;
     }
     .MenuHeader{
       display: block;
     }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, чтобы по-быстрому то

```css
li a {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,но у меня не отображается иконка для выпадающего меню
.MenuHeader{
       display: block;
     }